# How to implement update status by parallel reading file in Go?

Tags: go

I'm porting a program in C language. It is using two thread to work.
* Main thread keeps a status map with a read-write lock.
* Update thread keeps reading from a continuous growing file to update the status map. If it read failed, the user can press a button to re-read it.

What's the proper way to do same log in Go? Here is my prototype

```
var status = struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    M map[string]string
}
func readFile(filename string) {
    // open file
    for {
        status.Lock()
        // update status
        status.Unlock()
        // run forever util error occurs
    }
}
func main() {
  go readFile("sample.data") 
  go readFile("sample2.data") 
  for {
    status.RLock()
    fmt.Println(status.M)
    status.RUnlock()
    // wait for user command (eg. assign new file to read or stop old file or quit)
  }
}
```

I know how to use sync.RWMutex and goroutine, but the problem is how to handle the 'reopen the file', it is on other goroutine and maybe the gorouting have already quit for reading fail, or it may still running, I require to stop the gorouting and restart it.

Comment: You could use a couple channels to send messages between the threads (`readFile` could send on channel `A` to indicate an error, and then blocking read on channel `B` for proper response, while `main` could non-blocking read on channel `A` to check for error, prompt for user response if error, then send on `B` to let `readFile` know what to do next)

Comment: Though the stickler in me would probably change what everything's responsible for. I'd have `main` read the file and send each bit of update to `updateMap`, which would mutate the map. My reasoning being that all of the IO work is then done in `main` and we can just use a producer/consumer pattern. Or, quite frankly, cut out the asynchronous bit entirely and do this synchronously.

Comment: Could you reply a pseudo code as answer?